# League qualifications

Tags: word-hero

Word Hero has a series of 'leagues', however its not clear what determines how someone qualifies for a promotion. Is it based on number of games played, some kind of moving average for the score or percentile, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to

Help > Learn to Play > Player Ratings

in the app, it explains that it is based on a moving average of your last 50 scores, with some exceptions.  The score ranges are subject to change according to the help file, but are, at the time of this writing:

```
Not rated - <100
Bronze - 100 - 165
Silver - 165 - 240
Gold - 240 - 325
Platinum - 325 - 425
Diamond - 425+
```